# Window focus issue

Tags: winapi, opengl, focus, window

I am currently programming a graphics application with OpenGL and the Windows API in C++. Unfortunately the image freezes under certain conditions, such as when I'm resizing the window, and/or when my mouse isn't moving. Is there some sort of mechanism I can use in Win32 to ensure that the frames are constantly being processed?

Here's some pseudocode describing the basic flow of my program

Main Loop

```
while(running)
{
    if (PeekMessage(&Msg,NULL,0,0,PM_REMOVE))   
    {
        if (Msg.message==WM_QUIT)               
        {
            SetRunning(false);                  
        }
        else                                    
        {
            TranslateMessage(&Msg);             
            DispatchMessage(&Msg);              
        }
    }
    else
    {
        SwapBuffers(deviceContext);
    }
}
```

WndProc

```
switch(msg)
{

case WM_CLOSE:
{
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
}

case WM_SIZE:
{
    ResizeScreen(LOWORD(lParam),HIWORD(lParam));
    break;
}

}

return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
```

EDIT: I read the tutorial Kol linked to and made some edits, and now the frame rate is consistent even when the mouse is not moving. However the image still freezes when I'm moving or resizing the window, so I'd appreciate help on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [NeHe site](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) to learn the basics of OpenGL with Win32. [There](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/creating_an_opengl_window_%28win32%29/13001/) are detailed explanations about how the message loop should look like, what the WM_SIZE handler should do etc.

**EDIT**

The code which draws the scene and the buffer swapping should be put into the message loop, in an else branch after the `if (PeekMessage(...))` branch. See where the `DrawGLScene()` call is in the above mentioned NeHe example.

**EDIT2**

The problems were the followings:

- The scene renderer function was not called in the WM_SIZE and WM_MOVE handlers.
- The scene was drawn only once a second.

Comment: I read the tutorial and made some edits, and now the frame rate is consistent even when the mouse is not moving. However the image still freezes when I'm moving or resizing the window, so I'd appreciate help on that. I made some edits to the main post to show my changes.

Comment: Hmm... That doesn't seem to fix it either. Still freezing when I move/resize the window.

Comment: Can you compile the NeHe example? Does it run without freezing?

Comment: I've built the code from the NeHe tutorial directly and the frame rate still freezes when I resize the window (I set the color to red instead of black so I could actually get an idea of how frames were displaying). By the way, by freezing I mean the buffer swaps stop occurring temporarily (i.e. 0 FPS), not as in the application crashing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5113/discussion-between-kol-and-autobotam)

Comment: Please, please stop pointing people to Nehe :( They are horrible tutorials that rely on long dead ways of doing OpenGL and fail to teach anything about the way modern graphics engines work.

Comment: @Bethor That is your opinion. My experience is that the NeHe tutorials are great for beginners. What do you think is the best material for a beginner to start learning OpenGL? EDIT: Okay, I saw your list here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5926357/c-opengl-books/5935977#5935977